# Java software interface was hidden

Tags: windows

I have Windows server 2022 English and installed an ERP software which named Digiwin, when I open the configuration center of Digiwin, there are two configuration options missed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbXnV.jpg)

And when I checked another Windows server which version is Chinese and the two option are ok:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKN2U.jpg)

I have no idea how to adjust.

Thanks.

I expext the missed options can be recovery.

Comment: The main difference between the two images seems to be that one contains the product ID code, and the checkbox is ticked / checked, while the other screenshot shows that option is not checked, and the product ID is not present. Try entering the product ID and checking the checkbox, perhaps that will unlock the locked fields.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved, I installed Chinese language pack and switch interface language from English to Chinese, the issue fixed.

Thank you all.